# Reading filenames in a folder and storing them in XML using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I would like to know how one can write PHP code to read filenames from a particular folder and save the extracted filenames in an XML document?

An example of any part of this would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code example found at [`readdir()`](http://lv.php.net/readdir) manual a bit, and you're done! Something like this could work:

```
<?php
$out="<FileList>\n";
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $out.='<file>'.$file."</file>\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
$out.='</FileList>';
file_put_contents("./outfile.xml",$out);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using SimpleXML rather than handcrafting your XML. You don't want your system to choke whenever someone uses special characters in file names.

```
$out = simplexml_load_string('<files />');

$DI = new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir');
foreach ($DI as $file)
{
    if ($file->isFile())
    {
        $out->addChild('file', $file->getFilename());
    }
}

$out->asXML('files.xml');
```

Comment: Yes! Concatenated XML is da debil.

Comment: `isDot` will not omit directories though. 'isFile' would be a better check.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that the OP would want to omit directories but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Start looking at [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/function.glob.php) for reading the filenames of a directory. Work yourself through array-manipulation and look at the file-manipulation functions afterwards: [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-put-contents.php)